# Setting a variable to NULL after it has already been set a value: not working

Tags: php

`$row['genre']` is grabbing data from a database.

```
$genrelisty = $row['genre'];
$arr        = explode(', ', $genrelisty);
$var1       = $arr[0];
$var2       = $arr[1];
$var3       = $arr[2];
$var4       = $arr[3];
$var5       = $arr[4];

if (!empty($var2)) {
    $Genre2 = "Genre 2:";
} else {
    $var2 = NULL & $Genre2 = NULL;
}
if (!empty($var3)) {
    $Genre3 = "Genre 3:";
} else {
    $var3 = NULL & $Genre3 = NULL;
}
if (!empty($var4)) {
    $Genre4 = "Genre 4:";
} else {
    $var4 = NULL & $Genre4 = NULL;
}
if (!empty($var5)) {
    $Genre5 = "Genre 5:";
} else {
    $var5 = NULL & $Genre5 = NULL;
}
```

When I display `$var` it displays "0" instead of nothing.

Comment: else{$var2=NULL & $Genre2=NULL;} Don't do this... $var2=null; $genre2=null; That single ampersand isn't doing what you think it is. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: What do you think `$var2=NULL & $Genre2=NULL;` does? Those are two separate statements, not something to combine using an operator.

Comment: You should work on code readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $var2 = NULL & $Genre2 = NULL;
```

`&` is a bitwise operator. It cannot be used to combine statements.

Use `;` to separate statements.